# Java Card 3.0.5 build error with verifyPreComputedHash() method

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard

I'm testing java card digital signing and I'm getting a build error in Eclipse as follows:

> method verifyPreComputedHash(byte[], short, short, byte[], short,
>   short) of class javacard.security.Signature not found in export file
>   security.exp or   the method signature has changed.

I'm invoking the method with the following line, where data and sig are byte arrays (byte[]) and the others are shorts.

```
success = signature.verifyPreComputedHash(data, dataOffset, dataLength, 
                                          sig, sigOffset, sigLength);
```

This matches the 3.0.5 [spec definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html#verifyPreComputedHash(byte[],%20short,%20short,%20byte[],%20short,%20short)).

What I've read is that the verifyPreComputedHash didn't exist for 3.0.4 and earlier but I just verified that my Eclipse is pointing to jcdk3.0.5u3 (Project -> Properties -> Java Card Runtime -> Java Card SDK Home -> C:\javacard\jcdk3.0.5u3)

I also have no issues with signature.signPreComputedHash(), signature.verify(), or signature.sign()... They all work.

Lastly, the file "jcdk3.0.5u3\api_export_files\javacard\security\javacard\security.exp" isn't easily readable, but the string "verifyPreComputedHash" appears in the file. By comparison, the 3.0.4 security.exp doesn't have the string "verifyPreComputedHash". So it's really not clear to me why I'd get this error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you solved this question? Did you clean the project and build again? Note that these post-compile steps are out of normal order so sometimes it is useful to reset the build system, e.g. by removing the output folder altogether using your favorite file explorer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Interesting suggestion.  I exited Eclipse and then in the Eclipse project folder, I deleted the "bin" and "deliverables" folders.  I restarted Eclipse and rebuilt my project and both folders re-appeared, but so did the error:  `method verifyPreComputedHash(byte[], short, short, byte[], short, short) of class javacard.security.Signature not found in export file security.exp or the method signature has changed`

Comment: Dang. Well it is something that needed to be checked, so this one is off the list. The problem is that we cannot access your build environment. Maybe you could indicate the JC plugin that you're using so somebody may be able to try and replicate the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have much else to covey as far as build environment.  I'm using Eclipse win64 v4.8.0 that I downloaded from [Eclipse.org here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer), and the Java Card Development Kit 3.0.5u3 (java_card_kit-classic-3_0_5-u3-win32-bin-do-b26-20_jul_2018.msi) that I downloaded from [Oracle here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/javacard-sdk-2043229.html)